# Multivariate Time Series Forecasting of only 1 of the variables

Tags: python, time-series, multivariate-distribution

I have a dataset that has time series data in the following format -
1 column for the date,
5 dependent variables,
1 independent variable (need to predict)

I want to see if the dependent variables Granger Cause the independent variable.
For that should i run the granger test before or after the ADF test ?
Because the tutorial here runs it before the ADF test - https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/vector-autoregression-examples-python/

Also, after building the model. I would know the values of the dependent variables, I only need to predict the independent variable. How would i go about doing that ? because when following the tutorial it is predicting all the variables even those which are need to be input.

Thank you !